# Iframe event to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So, I'd like to trigger an event in my iframe like :

```
$('body').trigger('my_event');
```

And I'd like to bind this event on my main page that contains the iframe :

```
$('iframe').find('body').bind('my_event', function()
{
    console.log('My event !');
}
```

But this does not work. However, I can trigger the event from my iframe to my parent body. So i've got (in my iframe) :

```
$(top).find('body').trigger('my_event');
```

And in my main page :

```
$('body').bind('my_event', function()
{
    console.log('My event !');
}
```

And this works well. **Why ?**

And yes, I do know about the cross-domain policy. My main page and my iframe both are from the same domain.

Thanks !

Comment: Why: Because events do not magically transgress out of the document they occurred (or were triggered) in …

Comment: Since my second example does work, I guess events can "transgress" out of the document ?

Comment: No, since you are explicitly triggering it within the scope of the parent document. (You are not triggering it “to” the parent body, as you phrased it, but rather _on_.)

Comment: Try `$('iframe').contents() ...`.

Comment: In your parent window, get a handle on your iframe and add an event listener to it. `$('iframe').contents().on('my_event', function() {console.log('Parent sees event')});`

Answer (score 0):

This might be because at the moment you reference `$('iframe').find('body')` it's not loaded yet.

Try using *delegated binding*, something like this:

```
$(document).on('my_event', 'iframe body', function(e){
     console.log('My event !');
});
```

Check this for more info: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

**UPDATE:**

Looks like the parent won't catch an event from an iframe unless it's triggered on its element explicitly.

E.g. in your iframe:

```
parent.$(parent.document).trigger("my_event");
```

In the parent:

```
$(document).on('my_event', function(e){
      console.log('My event !');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it does not seem to work unfortunately. :(